# How can I publish a checkin without the publish_stream permission (with Dialog)?

Tags: facebook, permissions, dialog, checkin

I want to publish a checkin from an application and I have read the [Checkin Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/) to do so with an HTTP POST request.
Now I would like to do it, but without the publish_stream permission. Can I do the same thing with [Dialogs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/) (JavaScript SDK) ?
I tried with the FB.ui method, but I don't know how to do it properly.

FB.ui(
    {
        method: 'feed',
        message: 'My message',
        place: '110506962309835'
    }
);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Feed dialog does not take a `place` parameter – and Facebook say, this is “by design”. (See this bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/428651263853608)

So if you want to publish checkins, I’m afraid there is no way around it, you’ll have to use the API and make the post on behalf of the user, asking for the permission first.